# Rails Grape-Swagger: get current domain for base_path

Tags: ruby, api

I've got the following Grape root class definition

```
module Api
  class Root < Grape::API
    mount Api::Version1



    add_swagger_documentation :mount_path => 'docs', 
                              :base_path => "/api", 
                              :markdown => true, 
                              :hide_documentation_path => true
  end
end
```

The problem is that ":base_path" should include a full URL, and I don't know where to get it. 
I've checked ENV variable, and there is nothing close to the current domain. There is also no "request" object of any kind. Is there any way in Ruby I can just get the current domain, ie HTTP_HOST variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, for anyone wandering here after all these years (like I did), - this is the solution that worked for me:

```
add_swagger_documentation base_path: lambda { |request| "http://#{request.host}:#{request.port}" }
                          ... #other options
```

Basically you just have to pass a proc that yields `Grape::Request` instance, from which you can pull the host and port data.

Answer (score 0):

I've had decent luck using `http://localhost:9292/api`.  I think another alternative would be to keep these settings in a config yml file, and you could possibly set that based on RACK_ENV's value.